# Hadoop DFS permission issue when running job

Tags: permissions, hadoop

I'm getting this following permission error, and am not sure why hadoop is trying to write to this particular folder:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-*-examples.jar pi 2 100000
Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 100000
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Starting Job
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=myuser, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

Any idea why it is trying to write to the root of my hdfs?

**Update:** After temporarily setting hdfs root (/) to be 777 permissions, I seen that a "/tmp" folder is being written.  I suppose one option is to just create a "/tmp" folder with open permissions for all to write to, but it would be nice from a security standpoint if this is instead written to the user folder (i.e. /user/myuser/tmp)

Comment: Did you start hadoop with "myuser"?

Comment: No, I am using Cloudera, so hadoop is running as service, presumably as root

Comment: Try setting the permissions to / to 777 with hadoop fs -chmod and see what it writes.

Comment: @orangeoctopus - it is writing /tmp/hadoop-mapred -- is there a setting to change this location?

Comment: @spike - I'd prefer it if non-root users can run hadoop from their own accounts. I noticed it is writing /tmp to hdfs, so trying to figure out why that is occurring, so let me know if you have any ideas on that. thanks

Comment: When we set the root directory, eg /app/hadoop/ , this is is located on master. right? So that means all data are saved to master??

Comment: @Paschalis - the `mapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir` setting points to a location on HDFS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to get this working with the following setting:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir</name>
        <value>/user</value>
    </property>

    #...

</configuration>
```

Restart of jobtracker service required as well (special thanks to Jeff on Hadoop mailing list for helping me track down problem!)

Comment: thanks, ran into the very same problem. it's a pity this isn't the default value.

Comment: hhhm, it looks like if I set this, the permissions on mapred.system.dir (/hadoop/mapred/system) need to more permissive

Comment: I have the /mapred/system directory locked down to just the mapred user (mapred.system.dir=/mapred/system).  hdfs root (/) is set to only hdfs user too.  If you still have problems, let me know what errors you are getting

Comment: @stephenmulcahy - BTW, I just ran into permission issue with Pig, which is due to it having its own temp directory setting. more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194069/apache-pig-permissions-issue

Comment: What file did you add this too?

Hadoop Config or Hive Config?

Comment: @djc391 - It was added to mapred-site.xml (Hadoop config)

Comment: @dolan I am facing the same permission issue but I do not have control over the hdfs root directory. But looking at the /tmp directory, it has 777 permission. So I am wondering what causes this issue to me. `mapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir = ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/staging` and `hadoop.tmp.dir = /tmp/hadoop-${user.name}`. May be it tries to write some other dir in the hdfs root other than '/tmp'? Also, I see this error only for large number of input paths; For smaller inputs, it goes smoothly. I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: @sachin2182 -- Can you confirm you can create directories in hdfs's /tmp?  If you can, create one for your user, then try setting the paths in the config so they are hard-coded to your new directories (create all the children ones too -- e.g. mapred/staging) -- give them all 777 permissions as a starting test. Restart Hadoop, and then see if it still errors. Did you check /var/log/hadoop to see if you can figure out where it is trying to write (not sure if it'll tell you, but worth a look)?

Comment: @dolan -- I have permission to create dirs under /tmp in hdfs. It turns out that while parsing my input, there is some unexpected character (which is used to determine the output location) and the map-reduce system tries to write in root dir. I fixed my script to take care of the unexpected character and now the jobs run without any issues. Sorry for the confusion and it took me a while to figure that something is wrong with my input/script.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create the {mapred.system.dir}/mapred directory in hdfs using the following command

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /hadoop/mapred/
```

2) Give permission to mapred user

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown mapred:hadoop /hadoop/mapred/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a new user named "hdfs". Quite simple solution but not as clean probably.

Of course this is when you are using Hue with Cloudera Hadoop Manager (CDH3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the permission for hadoop root directory (/) instead of setting the permission for the system's root directory. Even I was confused, but then realized that the directory mentioned was of hadoop's file system and not the system's.

Comment: When you say "hadoop root directory", do you mean the root of HDFS? I chose not to make permissions in the HDFS root loose so that I could prevent users from writing to the root (and force them to one particular directory -- their "home": /user/<username>).

Comment: Thats right. The configuration in the above question seems to be incorrect. It should point to the specific directory on HDFS. In my case it was pointing to /opt/hadoop/mapred/local/staging. I gave the write permission to the directory and it was working just fine.

Comment: Are you saying the setting mapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir=/user is incorrect?  Note that I'm also referring to an HDFS location in my setting for this. Also, I'm using Cloudera in case that makes a difference.